# Problem displaying en-dash in imported bibliography items!

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I am importing a large bibliography from a citation manager and it seems that  the character `–` is not displayed correctly in latex. It is supposed to be an en-dash though.

I wouldn't want to change the characters one-by-one to -- . Where this problem come from? and as a workaround how to defined this character `–` in latex to replace it with an en-dash?

```
\documentclass{article}

 %with or without the following line, the en-dash is not displayed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{hwang_utility_2013}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{hwang_utility_2013}
Eun~Jung Hwang and Richard~A. Andersen.
\newblock The utility of multichannel local field potentials for
  brain–machine interfaces.
\newblock {\em Journal of Neural Engineering}, 10(4):046005, August 2013.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: accented A almost always implies an undeclared ut-8 encoding add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accented A almost always implies an undeclared utf-8 encoding

add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Note that bibtex isn't really utf-8 aware but as long as the characters are in titles rather than in author names that need to be sorted, you can usually get away with it.